# How can I bind to the Image property of a NSPopUpButtonCell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've created a `NSTableView`, and have set up all my bindings (via an `NSArrayController`).  I want one of the columns to have a `NSPopUpButtonCell`, but, instead of showing text, I want it to show an image - so the user can change the image from the `popup control`.

My column is bound (using the `SelectedObject` binding) to the correct property, and the the `NSPopUpButtonCell` is bound (using the `ContentValues` binding) to my complete list of images (which is from another `NSArrayController` containing an array of image names - NSStrings).

I've created a `NSValueTransformer` to convert an image name (NSString) to an NSImage, and have tested this works by creating an addition column with an `NSImageCell`, and that displays the image correctly.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm hoping I can target the binding at the `NSPopUpButtonCell`'s `image` property, rather than its `title` property.

Edit: I had the idea of trying to use an `NSAttributedString`, with an embedded image. But, the problem remains, in that I want the binding to use `setAttributedTitle`, rather than `setTitle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I've managed to solve this problem. I'm convinced there remains a more **correct** solution, but, for now, this'll do.

My solution:

- Change the Pop Up Button Cell > Menu to a custom class

  - [image: Menu]
  - [image: Custom Class]
- In the custom class, inherit from NSMenu:

  - `@interface RSMenu : NSMenu`
- Override `insertItemWithTitle`, and customize to your own needs.

For example:

```
-(NSMenuItem *)insertItemWithTitle:(NSString *)aString 
        action:(SEL)aSelector 
        keyEquivalent:(NSString *)charCode 
        atIndex:(NSInteger)index {

    NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:aString];
    NSMenuItem* menuItem = [super insertItemWithTitle:image ? @"" : aString 
            action:aSelector 
            keyEquivalent:charCode atIndex:index];

    if ( nil != image ) {
        [menuItem setImage:image];
    }   

    return menuItem;
}
```

And here is the result:

- [image: Result]

Hope this helps someone else.